# Escape asp/vbscript script tags

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

How to escape asp directive output

So i need print to page string with asp tags

```
<%
response.write "<%=Count%>"
%>
```

But I get error

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0409'
Unterminated string constant
```

So how to print script tags?

So i need get `<%=Count%>` not `Count`

There are any way instead of ?

```
<%
    response.write "<" & "%=Count%" & ">"
%>
```

Comment: i think you need encoding here ....

Comment: What about `<% Response.Write "<&#37=Count&#37>" %>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure you HTML encode before attempting to use `Response.Write()` something like this;

Here I use the HTML encoded value of `%` which is [`&#37`](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) to stop the VBScript run-time from spitting it's dummy *(but you can use anything even `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>` as has been suggested)*.

```vb
<%
Response.Write "<&#37=Count&#37>"
%>
```

Outputs:

```
<%=Count%>
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to use the `<script>` tag instead of `<% ... %>` for your code block:

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">
    Response.Write "<%= Count %>"
</script>
```

Output:

```
<%= Count %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could simply use the `&lt;` and `&gt;` character codes via a shorthand `Response.Write`:

```
<%= "&lt;%= Count %&gt;" %>
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it. Unlike `&#37` for `%`, `&lt;` for `<` is relatively transparent (as in you can look at the encoding and have some clue of what character it's going to produce even without looking it up), and (unlike numerical character encodings) the html named entities are generally not subject to language/locale/encoding issues. Plus, `<` and `>` are reserved characters in html, so it makes sense to encode them rather than the non-reserved `%`.

Comment: @Martha True, my point was just force the HTML encoding yourself. Whether `%` or `<>` doesn't matter the point is to get around the runtime borking encode part or all of the string.

Comment: Also OP wasn't using shorthand so didn't suggest it but really that's a given. Just splitting hairs but agree encoding the `<` and `>` makes more sense.