# Format to allow ASP Classic <% %> tags inside of a FileSystem object Writeline command

Tags: asp-classic

I have a script I am building that creates ASP Classic pages from form input.

I am using the file object to create the asp file.  It is working as intended, however I am slightly perplexed how to embed ASP CLASSIC code into the string.  The open tag works like this:

```
fname.WriteLine"<% DIM GENERIC_VAR"
```

This displays in the file properly, however the use of the close tag doesn't seem to want to work.  Even my IDE is indicating a formatting issue.  Usually in the instances I need to replace a " (double quote) a ' (single quote) will work, but in this case I get compile errors (Unterminated string constant) or the file doesn't create the line as expected.  I know about doubling up "" but so far haven't had any luck. Thanks.

Side note as an example, I just need to be able to print this into the line of the file:

```
fname.WriteLine"%>"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape asp/vbscript script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291678/escape-asp-vbscript-script-tags)

Comment: It does get me going in the right ballpark.  Although it literally pastes the text into the file as "<&#37
dim varname
&#37>
Which means the file it creates assumes it is HTML text instead of the tag, and just prints the line onto the screen if that makes sense.  Going to try the alternative variations now.

Comment: &lt;%
varname
%&gt;>
Gets written in when I try the 2nd variation.  So what is happening is, it is saving the file in the encoded format, and not as the <% or %>, so when it renders the HTML only then it displays as the <% %> tags versus executing them.

Comment: I think what makes my question different than the replied answer, is that question wanted to do it inline inside of the ASP script via a response.write command.  Whereas, the writeline is going to make a new line in an external file, and so the encoding needs to happen before it gets written down if that makes sense.    Appreciate any more thoughts on this.  thanks!

Comment: I am still going to +1 your comment though, because it was helpful and expedited a rapid turn around.  But it appears in this case, it is not actually a duplicate because of what is needing to be done (response.write vs write.line)  But the solution I was able to craft is posted below in case someone else ever has this issue.  Thanks user292942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
openasp  = "<"
openasp  = openasp & "% "
closeasp = " %"
closeasp = closeasp & ">"
```

Set up the ASP tags like above.
Then Wrap them in line as needed for example:

```
fname.WriteLine openasp & "DIM VAR_NAME" & closeasp
```