# Is there a method to write a response in an EJS template?

Tags: ejs

With classic ASP you can do a `response.write('foo')` inside `<% ... %>`. Is this possible with EJS?

The current workaround is to use 2 tags, one for logic, one for output:

```
<%
let someString = generateSomeStringHere()
%>
<%- someString %>
```

I do understand that some will recommend generating `someString` outside of the template but let's say for the sake of argument that is not desirable.

We would like to do:

```
<%
let someString = generateSomeStringHere()
ejs.write(someString);
%>
```

Comment: <%
Response.Write(someString)
%>

does the same thing as 

<%=someString%>

I don't know if that helps you at all but just throwing that out there.

Comment: Yes, I posted that workaround. My case is perhaps special view logic, say a loop, writing output without ending the `%>` tag and starting a new `<%=sendMyVar%>`.

Comment: Oh you know what .. is that the problem the %> part doesn't translate when you output it sort of thing?  That is an ASP encoding thing, and here is a link to a question about that in which I got some help personally SEE HERE:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70383860/format-to-allow-asp-classic-tags-inside-of-a-filesystem-object-writeline-c

Comment: Nooe. I just want to generate/stream out HTML without closing and reipening with `%><%=`

Comment: Ahh I see .. wish I could be of more help.